# How do I Post my data to a mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning to build a simple MERN application to take user data and upload it to a mongoDB collection, and I can't seem to figure out why I'm receiving a 400 BAD REQUEST error when attempting to post the user data. It's currently being run on local server. I'm currently unable to find a post that directly solves my particular issue. I have used post man to send my post requests.

Here is my User.js for the data schema i have placed it in a folder called routes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        min:6
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:255,
        min:6
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        max:1024,
        min:6
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.time
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

i have this auth.js file for routes, i have placed it in a routes folder, i have a .env file to store some credentials to connect to the database.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../model/User');


router.post('/register', async(req,res)=>{
    const user = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    try{
     const savedUser = await user.save();
     res.send(savedUser);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
});

module.exports= router;
```

This is my index.js file, i think it works alright cause i see server is up and running on port 3000 and connected to database.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//import routes
const authRoute =  require('./routes/auth');



dotenv.config();

//connect to DB
mongoose.connect('process.env.DB_CONNECT',{ useNewUrlParser: true },()=>{
    console.log('connected to the database');
});

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());

//route middlewares
app.use('/api/user', authRoute);

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server is up and running on port 3000');
});
```

i have use post man to send post requests but i am met with 400 bad request

Comment: Could you try outputting the error in the terminal?

Comment: there is no error in the terminal. The terminal outputs:

Comment: outputs connected to the database and server is up and running on port 3000

Comment: in POSTMAN what does your URL looks like?

Comment: localhost:3000/api/user/register

Comment: What is your server log? It seems to send you 400

Comment: Code works fine for me `http://localhost:3000/api/user/register` this is your `URL` looks like and make sure you are sending `POST` request in `postman`  and send `JSON` data